# Why does stretching elements over table cells overlap with elements in other cells?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, html-table

I'm developing an React(0.13.3) SPA, with bootstrap 3.2.0, where users can select different university courses from a list, which puts them in a table.(For context see here http://master-helper.herokuapp.com/)
My issue is that courses, once placed in the table, can stretch over more than one quarter(LP). To account for this; I stretch such course-elements(actually boostrap buttons) with width:200%. Making them stretch over two table cells. If there already is an element present in such a cell they overlap each other.

What I want to accomplish is, without doing a hack, stop the elements from overlapping and instead make one of the two elements jump down to the space below -on the same table row. Just as if the bigger course-element was present in the second cell as well.
It doesn't matter which of them that jumps down.

Here's the table code with the two overlapping courses.
http://www.bootply.com/F1Xl0Kdb4D

An option is to use the boostrap grid instead of a table. But in general that feels messy for what I'm trying to achieve.